# Wrong result accessing device by JNA

Tags: java, windows, dll, jna

I trying to access a device using JNA

The first command return a statusCode 263 insteadof zero.

I searched and found this code, means "INVALID_DEVICE_NAME". The device's manual say:

> *The MCI_OPEN_TYPE flag must be specified and the lpstrDeviceType member of the structure identified by lpOpen must contain the device
>   name (in our case “DictCtrl”)*.

Is there any error in my code?

The "same" code works in a compiled delphi application, my device is recognized.

```
public class Main {
    public static final int MCI_OPEN = 0x0803;
    public static final int MCI_OPEN_TYPE = 0x00002000;
    public static final int MCI_STATE_STOP = 0x00000001;
    public static final int MCI_OPEN_SHAREABLE = 0x00000100;

public static Winmm winmmLib = Winmm.INSTANCE;

public interface Winmm extends StdCallLibrary {
    Winmm INSTANCE = (Winmm) Native.loadLibrary("winmm", Winmm.class);

    int mciSendCommandA(int IDDevice, int uMsg, int fdwCommand, Structure dwParam);
}

public static class TagmciOpenParmsa extends Structure {

    public int dwCallback;
    public int wDeviceID;
    public String lpstrDeviceType;
    public String lpstrElementName;
    public String lpstrAlias;

    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "dwCallback", "wDeviceID", "lpstrDeviceType", "lpstrElementName", "lpstrAlias" });
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TagmciOpenParmsa tagmciOpenParmsa = new TagmciOpenParmsa();

    tagmciOpenParmsa.lpstrDeviceType = "DictCtrl";


    int ret = winmmLib.mciSendCommandA(0, MCI_OPEN, MCI_OPEN_TYPE, tagmciOpenParmsa); // | MixerConstants.MCI_OPEN_SHAREABLE
    System.out.println(ret);
}
```

}

Comment: I realized the device's drive maybe is a "32 bits driver" and I trying to use on a 64 bits plattaform/application. My delphi application runs in 32 bits and works.

This may be my problem?

Comment: Native code must match the JVM arch, i.e. 32-bit with 32-bit, 64-bit with 64-bit.  You can't mix the two sizes.

Comment: Yes, but I'm using java64 and loading a windows dll (winmm.dll), without specifying 32 or 64 for that DLL...

But my device drive is a 32bit only.